# Will the company rescind the job offer if I request to start at a much later date (2-3 months later than the original date)?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer

I accepted a conditional job offer; no official start date was given unless I meet all the requirements. However, through my email exchanges with the HR manager, the company would like me to start in early Feb as they have a structured onboarding process for new incoming staff like orientation, training, etc. At that point of time, I agreed. However, recently some personal family things/plans have came up and I won't be able to start until April/May. Will it be too long of a wait for them if I respectfully request to start at a much later date? Will they rescind the offer?

Just wanted to ask here if anyone had similar experience and what happened? or if anyone can give me any advice/thoughts?

Comment: It's highly unlikely they'll rescind the job offer for _requesting_ this. It's more than possible they'll rescind the offer if you insist - but nobody can tell you that as it depends entirely on how urgently they need you to start, and also on how good you are.

Comment: Exactly what they might do is pure speculation but my experience is that most companies are quite willing to accommodate such requests as long as they are reasonable.  Be honest about your reasons and see what the result is.

Comment: Have you in fact met all the requirements, or is the HR manager jumping the gun?

Comment: I don't want to second guess your life, but will those "personal family things/plans" really take up all your time between February and May? What were you going to do about your current job with regard to those? If you only need a few weeks for your family stuff, I suggest starting in February but negotiating some unpaid time off to do your family plans. The company would almost certainly prefer that to a May start.

Comment: I'd imagine a reasonable timeframe is good enough and one that is based on any prior obligation with your current employer (such as contract notices, etc).

Answer (score 2):

> Will they rescind the offer?

Maybe yes, maybe no. You'll just have to ask.

I recommend asking "intelligently": state your issue and ask to come up with a solution that's mutually agreeable. Not everything needs to be black or white. Example: Maybe you can attend the onboarding and then do remote or part-time work until your home family situation improves.

Answer (score 2):

> Will they rescind the offer?

In general asking will not get the offer cancelled, unless this is the 42nd time you have asked for some modification.

> Will it be too long of a wait for them if I respectfully request to
> start at a much later date?

It all depends on their situation.

Companies hire because they have a position to fill. They may have somebody quitting, or somebody retiring. They may have fired somebody. They may need to fill the position because they won a new contract, or are opening a new location.

If they can't convince you to start in February, and not too much time has gone by since you accepted, they could call one of the other finalists, and see if they want your position. If they say yes, the company will rescind your offer.

If you wait until closer to February, they still might rescind the offer if they believe they can get somebody else before May. Or if they think you might keep delaying.

If you can reduce the time conflict to a week or two in the middle of the period, and then take a leave of absence for that short window, they might be agreeable to have you start in February and then have you in a non-pay status for those weeks. I am assuming you won't have enough paid leave during your first few months, but if you do they might not be upset about a few weeks.

In the past I did negotiate a delay of a few weeks due to not wanting to put in my two weeks notice the day before leaving on a two week business trip.

I knew somebody else who delayed their start date because between accepting the offer, and the submission of their notice, the current company announced a change to the pension program. This change would allow them to pull the cash balance out when they leave if they were still an employee at the start of the next month. If they left sooner they had to wait until they were in their sixties to get the cash/payments. The new company agreed to let them delay for a few weeks.